# Ajax .load() returning 'undefined error in jQuery 3.5, same line works in jQuery 2.10

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm migrating some Bootstrap3 sites to Bootstrap4, and I've been using a lot of simple ajax calls like:

```
var aloader= "/images/spinner.gif"; 
$(#selector).html(aloader).load("ajax script",{var1:param1,var2:param2});
```

to load a ajax response into a div, in response to an event, and display a spinner while it's happening.

The old site uses jQuery 2.1 and the new 3.5. The code works in the old site, but the new throws a JS error that '.load() is undefined'.

As far as I can tell this should work, [per the docs](https://api.jquery.com/load/#load-url-data-complete).

Comment: It appears that the close was too hasty. The question is appears to be about the [load function](https://api.jquery.com/load/#load-url-data-complete) and not the load-event. I've voted to re-open. (PS. ensure to use potentially valid placeholders, instead of merely "ajax script", eg. "data/foo.json").

Comment: Can you let us know which jquery you've included exactly?  Is it `jquery.3.5.1.slim.js`?  If your js file name has `slim` in it, then you need the full version for ajax requests

Comment: @Mitya but it's on a chain from `.html()` - so some form of jquery must be loaded.   Error implies the `slim` build.

Comment: Yes it has .slim in the name. grr. The template and framework for our custom Bootstrap is set to that. I did not know this.

Comment: Bit surprised custom bootstrap would have slim as it also excludes various animations

Comment: Yes It appears to be an error on the part of the folks writing the documentation for it...it's just getting rolled out as a beta  here; I'll bet their working code is right, but I was going by the docs...